# Select only one combination of two columns

Tags: sql

I have a table which contains for each row the counterpart. For example:

```
┏━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃ Column 1 ┃ Column 2 ┃
┣━━━━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━━┫
┃ A        ┃ B        ┃
┣━━━━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━━┫
┃ B        ┃ A        ┃
┗━━━━━━━━━━┻━━━━━━━━━━┛
```

I want only one combination:

```
┏━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃ Column 1 ┃ Column 2 ┃
┣━━━━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━━┫
┃ A        ┃ B        ┃
┗━━━━━━━━━━┻━━━━━━━━━━┛
```

What would such a statement look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
select *
from t
where column1 < column2;
```

This assumes that *all* pairs are really in the table (or at least the first of each pair is in the table).

Or, here is another way:

```
select least(column1, column2) as column1, greatest(column1, column2) as column2
from t
group by least(column1, column2), greatest(column1, column2);
```

This works even if only half of some pairs are in the table.